# Frequency issues in simulink interface with arduino

Tags: simulink, pwm

I'm trying to generate 6 PWM signals by comparing sine and triangular waves on simulink.In the scope I'm getting the frequency of PWM signals as 50 HZ. But when I deploy the model onto arduino, the frequency of the PWM signal is getting reduced to around 15 HZ .How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

whether you've downloaded arduino library for matlab simulink? PWM output later on arduino digital pins are connected to the scope matlab